# How to show video player when the application is in minimised

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-video-player

I am making a video streaming application. I want my application to show the video player in a tiny window when the app is minimised while playing like amazon prime app.Is there any way to implement this

Answer (score 0):

This feature is known as pictures in picture mode. I used this plugin [pip_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/pip_flutter) to implement this feature.